# Can't use Microsoft.Office.Core - no reference for version 12

Tags: c#, com, powerpoint, office-interop

I'm trying to use the Powerpoint Interop addin for a C# Winform program. That part seems to be ok, but the namespace Microsoft.Office.Core (needed for MsoTriState) is giving me problems.

I have looked around the internet for help on this, and the consensus is to add a reference from the COM tab to the Microsoft Office 12 Object Library. Unfortunately, I only have version 15, and the program isn't accepting that (errors below). I have the using reference set up ok.

Is the only way around it to install Office 2007? Or is there a way to force the program to accept version 15? I'm on VS 2010.

```
Errors: "the type "Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'office, version 12.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, Piblic key tokem = 71e9bce111e9429c'

"cannot convert from 'Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState [xxx.NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client.AssemblyAttributes.cs]' to 'Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState'    *projectfilepath*
```

Code:

```
using Core = Microsoft.Office.Core;
using PowerPoint = Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint;


        PowerPoint.Presentation file; 
        int slideIndex = 0;

        public PowerpointForm(string path)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var app = new PowerPoint.Application();

            var pres = app.Presentations;

            file = pres.Open(path, Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue, Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue, Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse);

        }
```

etc